# Python failure to manually import module

Tags: python-3.x, module

I have a python script (`test.py`) that requests the following imports:

```
from MolKit import Read
```

The module must be installed via [ADFR Suite](https://ccsb.scripps.edu/adfr/downloads/) which creates a separate directory for the module with the `_init_.py` file at the top. And, I have edited the `~/.bashrc` to append:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/ThoughtfulHistorian/ADFRsuite-1.0/ADFRsuite_x86_64Linux_1.0/CCSBpckgs/MolKit"
```

Before running `source ~/.bashrc`. Still, the script returns an import failure:

```
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from MolKit import Read
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MolKit'
```

I am running `Python 3.8.10` on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the directory *containing* the package directory which needs to be on PYTHONPATH, not the package directory itself.

Instead of

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/ThoughtfulHistorian/ADFRsuite-1.0/ADFRsuite_x86_64Linux_1.0/CCSBpckgs/MolKit"
```

use

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/ThoughtfulHistorian/ADFRsuite-1.0/ADFRsuite_x86_64Linux_1.0/CCSBpckgs"
```